# Как починить PyCharm на Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pycharm

Установил PyCharm Community 2022.1 через snap на Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Потом скачал проект с гитхаба через Get From VCS и после решил добавить интерпретатор через настройки, но вылазиет ошибка "Directory /home/user/project/venv/bin/python not found". Как ее решить?
По умолачанию в дистрибутиве установлен Python версии 3.10.4.

Comment: Полачаю что нужно выбрать или создать интерпретатор, о чем ПЧ вам настойчиво семафорит в  правом нижнем углу окна программы

Comment: @Namerek Пытался создать, вот что происходит: https://i.imgur.com/gQ388L0.png , https://i.imgur.com/kMsm5is.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6r3fd8w, Вот так попробуйте

Comment: @Namerek не помогло, но папка venv создалась не полностью, и если ее попробовать удалить из pycharm'а, то https://i.imgur.com/6Ndql15.png

Comment: @Антон удаляйте папку venv не из pycharm, а из файлового менеджера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло следующее

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```